# Problem with returning dynamically allocated 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

When I print the 2D array inside the function, it gives me the desired output but when I return the array and try to print it in main, it gives no output.

```
int** getPascal(int size)
{

    int i,j;
    int **pTri = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        pTri[i] = (int *)malloc((i+1) * sizeof(int));
        j++;
    }

    pTri[0][0] = 1;
    for(i = 1 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        pTri[i][0] = 1;
        for(j = 1; j < i; j++)
        {
            pTri[i][j] = pTri[i-1][j-1] + pTri[i-1][j];
        }
        pTri[i][i] = 1;
    }
    // pTri prints properly here
    return pTri;
}

int main()
{

    int size;
    scanf("%d",&size);

    int **pascalTriangle = getPascal(size);
    // printing pascalTriangle gives no output.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _no output_? Random values? Crashes?

Comment: Undefined behavior using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: Can you show the part of the code of printing the output?

Comment: Don't cast the result returned from `malloc()` etc. - it is unnecessary, and can mask the serious error of a missing prototype.

Comment: @EOF I agree it would be undefined behaviour if he were using a pointer to an int, for example `int *p; *p=10`, and then returning that pointer, but since he is allocating memory, what is the problem?

Comment: @alrevuelta `j++` after `int i,j;`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your `print` function? Mine prints the correct values in both sections of the code. Try using it:

```c
void printFunc(int **pascalArray, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (i+1); j++)
        {
            printf("%d", pascalArray[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I tried with `size = 5` and I get in both places:

> 1
>   11
>   121
>   1331
>   14641
>   1
>   11
>   121
>   1331
>   14641

Comment: My compiler was probably bugged or something. I switched to a different compiler and it worked. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Can you try with the previous compiler with `static int **pTri`